# git push does not update files on remote server

Tags: git, push

I have set up a git repository on my local machine and a bare repository on a linode box. When doing a git push there are no errors but I do not see the file on the remote server. The sequence of commands I followed was below:

On remote:

```
abhijat@kangaroo:~$ mkdir dev
abhijat@kangaroo:~$ cd dev && git init --bare
```

On local machine:

```
krypton:test abhijat$ git init
krypton:test abhijat$ vim app.py
krypton:test abhijat$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/abhijat/dev/test/.git/
krypton:test abhijat$ git add .
krypton:test abhijat$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   app.py
#
krypton:test abhijat$ git commit -m 'test first commit'
[master (root-commit) 3bee148] test first commit
 1 files changed, 16 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 app.py
krypton:test abhijat$ git remote add origin abhijat@linode:~/dev
krypton:test abhijat$ git push -v origin master
Pushing to abhijat@linode:~/dev
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 298 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To abhijat@linode:~/dev
   01a0e08..2273564  master -> master
```

But when I check on the linode the file is absent:

```
abhijat@kangaroo:~/dev$ ls -ltr
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  4 abhijat abhijat 4096 Sep  8 10:17 refs
drwxr-xr-x  2 abhijat abhijat 4096 Sep  8 10:17 info
drwxr-xr-x  2 abhijat abhijat 4096 Sep  8 10:17 hooks
-rw-r--r--  1 abhijat abhijat   73 Sep  8 10:17 description
drwxr-xr-x  2 abhijat abhijat 4096 Sep  8 10:17 branches
-rw-r--r--  1 abhijat abhijat   23 Sep  8 10:17 HEAD
-rw-r--r--  1 abhijat abhijat   66 Sep  8 10:57 config
drwxr-xr-x 12 abhijat abhijat 4096 Sep  8 11:03 objects
abhijat@kangaroo:~/dev$ find . -name app.py
abhijat@kangaroo:~/dev$
```

Am I missing something obvious here? The communication is via ssh and the keys are set up as expected, I can login without a password. However the file does not get copied to the remote server.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git doesn't work that way on the server side.  The files are highly compressed and grouped into chunks so you can't find a particular file.

To test your git server, create another clone in another directory and see if app.py is there.

```
git clone abhijat@linode:~/dev dev2
```

Comment: Ah, that is something I had missed entirely. I cloned the repository on the server and I then saw the file there. So I suppose the workflow for now will be to develop locally, push to the linode and then login to the linode and clone the repo. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this mean that to have a client-server style architecture you need to have 2 clients (1 on client and 1 on server) + a cryptic repository (on server)?

Comment: From what I understood from DigitalGhost's answer the idea is that the repository to which I pushed does not contain the files as-is but it has the ability to serve out files as part of the cloning operation. So you always need a server (of course) but it will not serve plaintext files, clients (anywhere, remote or local) will need to clone the repo contents.

Comment: The key point here is that you have a 'bare' repository on your remote (kangaroo).  A bare repository does not have a local checkout - a local working tree.  This is the standard git way of working with a remote to which you are pushing files.  You *can* push to a non-bare repository on a remote, but you will have to override the standard git settings.  Probably better to use two-repository solution on the remote as suggested by Kyle Chadha below.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to both **push to the repo and have the files update**, you can create a server-side git hook to checkout the files after they've been pushed. In the **server** side git `/hooks/` directory create a file named `post-receive` and add the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

Then give the file proper permissions using `chmod +x post-receive`

*Note: the above code assumes your git directory and deployed files are in different directories. Update the file depending on how you want things configured.*

**More info & a detailed explanation here:**
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project to present the contents of a branch/revision/tag of a repo on a virtual FS. It's based on fuse and libgit2. It's in the very early stages at the moment but it can show you the files/directories in a revision and their contents. If you ask to use a branch, if the branch is moved, it will refresh the virtual FS on the fly. Just in case: **early stages** so no LFS, no submodules, no... whatever fancy feature you are thinking of? None of that. Just trees and blobs in git jargon.

https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod